# jQuery detect if form has a value to be submitted and jquery message plugin show

Tags: jquery, html

jQuery detect if form has a value to be submitted and jQuery message plugin show. here is my code:

html:

```
<form name="sample" method="post" action="test.php?success" autofocus id="sample">
            <input type="text" id="text" class="text">
            <input type="submit" id="submit" class="submit">
</form>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sample').submit(function(){
        $.ajax({  
      type: "POST",  
      url: 'test.php?success',
      data:$('#sample').serialize(),
      success: function() {  
          $.msg({ 
            fadeIn : 500,
            fadeOut : 200,
            timeOut : 800,
            content : 'Successfully Saved',
            css:{
                border : '5px solid #C5C6C6',
                background : '#EFFBFF',
            },

          })};
        });
        });
})
```

Comment: what about http://jqueryvalidation.org/ ?

Comment: i just want to know how will i know if a form submit a value and it will alert a message.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the input has value using the [jQuery .val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method.  Using this you have several options:

- Use it inside a value-changed handler for the textbox and only enable the `Submit` button when the input has a value
- Use it within the `.submit()` event you're already handling.  If there isn't a value cancel the submit.

As usual, having the server handle this as well is required (in case the form is submitted without javascript).

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following code just after the **$('#sample').submit(function(){**

```
var text = $("#text").val();
if (text == '')
{
    alert("Message is missing!!");
    return;
}
```